# Trying to revise a formula I was once given. How many rectangular prisms are in a $n \times n \times n$ cube?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I post it the other day. The only answer I got is that the total number of rectangular prisms in a cube is equal to ${n+1 \choose 2}^3$. But using $n=2$, I found the formula to be wrong. When counting by hand, you will only get $21$ distinct rectangular prism, including single unit cubes. But with the formula, there are $27$ prisms.

Comment: Sorry for the slew of edits. It took a couple tries to get the title right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some.  There are eight unit cubes, one size two cube, six $1 \times 2 \times 2$ blocks, and twelve $1 \times 1 \times 2$ blocks, for a total of $27$

Comment: How you have six 1 by 2 by 2? Aren't there only 4. Looking from the top down, there are two vertical ones and two horizontal ones. I didn't see the rest two prisms.?

Comment: There are a total of six.  Two with the short direction left/right, two with the short direction up/down, two with the short direction front/back.  If the cube is centered on the origin, each of the three coordinate axes passes through two blocks.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to count the up and down ones. I thought they are the same as left to right.

Comment: The same issue exists with $1 \times 1 \times 2$, so there are $27$ total.